# How can I count the number of characters in a multiline file?

Tags: python, readfile

I have been asked to create a function that returns the total number of characters in a file (including newline characters) whose name is given as a parameter. My code seems to work fine for single line files, but it won't total the characters in a multi-line file.

```
def file_size(filename):
"""returns a count of the number of characters in the file 
whose name is given as a parameter."""

filename = open(filename)
lines = filename.readlines()
for line in lines:     
    length = len(line[::-1])
    return length
    
filename.close()
```

Comment: A better answer is `return os.stat(filename).st_size`.  Or, even, `return len(filename.read())`.

Comment: it would be unusual for such a project, but does the file contain multi-byte characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) states (emphasis mine):

> **To read a file’s contents, call `f.read(size)`**, which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string (in text mode) or bytes object (in binary mode). **`size` is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned;** it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory.

So, we can do the following:

- read in the file's contents using `.read()` without a `size` parameter
- count the number of characters in said file by using `len()` on the result of the call to `.read()`:

```py
len(filename.read())
```

---

That being said, to fix your immediate issue, you have an indentation error; you return after the first iteration of the `for` loop. This:

```py
for line in lines:     
    length = len(line[::-1])
    return length
```

should be:

```py
for line in lines:     
    length = len(line[::-1])
return length
```

so that you only return once all the lines have been processed.

Comment: Yeah I initially thought that the return line was meant to be aligned with the for loop but when I try that the Pylint checker says "Unreachable Code".  Thanks for the tips on reading a large file!

Comment: The `.close()` looks like it comes after the `return`, which would make it unreachable. Put it before the un-indented return statement, or, even better, [use a context manager](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#the-with-statement-approach).